# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null when trying to create an embed using discord.js v14.7.1

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The specific problem part is
`**module.exports = class HelpCommand extends Command {**`

The entire help.js file is (excluding urls and stuff):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Command } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
 
module.exports = class HelpCommand extends Command {
  constructor() {
    super('help', {
      description: 'List all available commands.',
    });
  }
 
  async exec(message) {
    const help = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#F8F7D8')
      .setTitle('TITLE')
      .setURL('URL')
      .setAuthor({
        name: 'NAME',
        iconURL: 'URL',
        url: 'URL',
      })
      .setDescription('Commands for NAME')
      .setThumbnail('URL')
      .addFields(
        { name: '/play', value: 'Used to play the music' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: '/pause', value: 'Used to pause the music', inline: true },
        { name: '/mp3', value: 'Used to convert a youtube link to an mp3', inline: true },
        { name: '/skip', value: 'Used to skip the music', inline: true }
      )
      .setImage('URL')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({
        text: 'NAME',
        iconURL: 'URL',
      });
 
    await message.channel.send({ embed: help });
  }
};
```

I tried changing it around but i'm new to coding and don't know what i'm doing. I'm using discord.js v14.7.1 and have been trying to convert my code into an embed. The code is a slash command and will send the embed when the user sends /help.

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is a sign of a broken reference or a circular reference. In this case, it's a broken reference.

discord.js does not export anything of type "Command" so when you `const { Command } = require('discord.js');`, that ends up being undefined. I'd make sure this is the correct place you are attempting to import.